# How to get a list of user accounts from HSQL?

Tags: hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB 2.2.8 and need to figure out how to get a list of all user accounts. In Oracle I'd query DBA_USERS but in HSQLDB I'm not sure? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS
```